# How to set accessibility attributes within .NET 's MenuItems, _without_ JavaScript

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, accessibility, wai-aria

I am working on a sidenav that is built on .NET MenuItems like so:

```
<asp:MenuItem value="19" Text="Profile" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem value="0" Text="Overview" ToolTip="Overview" Selected="true"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem value="2" Text="My Info & Email Subscriptions"  ToolTip="My Info & Email Subscriptions"></asp:MenuItem>
```

In HTML, the output produces a series of nested tables around each MenuItem which looks like this:

```
<div id="_links" class="span-3">
    <table id="FormUserControl__tabMenu" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="clear:left;">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="FormUserControl__tabMenun0">
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                 <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;">
                                      <a style="text-decoration:none;">
                                          <div id="FormUserControl__tabMenu_ctl00__tabMenuItemPanel" class="myAccountHeading    ">
                                              Profile
                                          </div>
                                       </a>
                                  </td>
                             </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)" title="Overview" id="FormUserControl__tabMenun1">
                 <td>
                     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                     <tbody>
                         <tr>
                             <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('FormUserControl$_tabMenu','0')" style="text-decoration:none;">
                                 <div id="FormUserControl__tabMenu_ctl01__tabMenuItemPanel" class="sideNav">
                                     Overview
                                  </div>
                              </td>
                          <tr>
                      <tbody>
                  </td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

How can I add to add accessibility role and aria-level to these innermost divs?  The goal is to achieve accessibility compliance. For example:

```
 <div role="heading" aria-level="[2]">Profile</div>
```

I have looked through MSDN documentation and it looks like there isn't a way to add those attributes within the intial MenuItem declaration.
I also tried adding `role` and `aria-level` attributes within CSS, which I know is hacky, but I figured since `content` can be set, it was worth trying. That doesn't work.
I could readily do this in JavaScript, but I really want to avoid involving that, it's a last resort and I do know how to do that.

Is there a way to change the MenuItem output to involve role and aria-level?  Or, is there a way to have it output a header instead of a div nested within two tables?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you'd need to override the rendering. I don't believe there is any built in way.

Comment: @dman2306 drat, okay, thankyou.  That's what I was afraid of, haha